# Using SysInetHTMLEditor in Ax 2009

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, html-editor

I need to provide a HTML editor functionality in Dynamics Ax 2009.

I figure out a button in a my form the call the html editor provided by ***SysInetHTMLEditor***.

I can call the form with code like this:

```
SysInetHTMLEditor editor;
;

editor = new SysInetHTMLEditor();
editor.run();
```

But I have not idea how to use the return, setting the initial text and so on.

I still searching documentation about the class but I can't found it.

Someone can provide me some example?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. First, build a class that extends SysInetHTMLEditor.

build a method text:

```
str text(str text = '')
{
    int i;
;
    if (prmisdefault(text))
        return super();

    i = strscan(text, '<body', 1, strlen(text));
    if (i)
    {
        text = strdel(text, i, strscan(text, '>', i, strlen(text))-i+1);
    }

    return super(text);
}
```

- use "this.text(sometext)" to set initial text (usually on new method)
- override save() to save the text (get it with this.text())
- override caption method to change caption
- override canClose() to save before exit
- override isToolEnabled for control tools:

  boolean isToolEnabled(int commandId, int tab)
  {
  switch (tab)
  {
      case #TABSource:
          switch (commandId)
          {
              case #TOOL_SAVE:
                  return true;
          }
          return false;

  ```
  case #TABPreview:
      return false;

  case #TABNormal:
      switch (commandId)
      {
          case #TOOL_SAVEAS:
          case #TOOL_NEW:
          case #TOOL_OPEN:
          case #TOOL_MENU_ELEMENT:

          case #TOOL_MAKEABSOLUTE:
          case #TOOL_BRINGTOFRONT:
          case #TOOL_SENDTOBACK:
          case #TOOL_BRINGFORWARD:
          case #TOOL_SENDBACKWARD:
          case #TOOL_BRINGABOVETEXT:
          case #TOOL_SENDBELOWTEXT:
          case #TOOL_LOCKELEMENT:

          case #TOOL_INSERTWEBPART:
          case #TOOL_INSERTACTIVEX:
          case #TOOL_INSERTWEBLET:
          case #TOOL_INSERTAXAPTAMENU:
          case #TOOL_THEME:
              return false;


          case #TOOL_INSERTBOOKMARKLINK:
          case #TOOL_HELPSYSTEM:
          case #TOOL_INSERTHELPLINKMENU:
          case #TOOL_INSERTFORMRUNLINK:
          case #TOOL_INSERTEXTHELPLINK:
          case #TOOL_INSERTFIELDLINK:
          case #TOOL_INSERTMENUDISPLAYLINK:
          case #TOOL_INSERTMENUOUTPUTLINK:
          case #TOOL_INSERTMENUACTIONLINK:
          case #TOOL_INSERTCLASSLINK:
          case #TOOL_INSERTMETHODLINK:
          case #TOOL_INSERTFUNCTIONLINK:
          case #TOOL_INSERTPROPERTYLINK:
          case #TOOL_INSERTHELPTITLE:
          case #TOOL_INSERTIFRAME:
              return false;
      }
  ```

  }
  return true;
  }